# can we write and open pdf file using file handling in php

Tags: php, html

I am using file handling in php to create write and then read pdf file. The problem is it creates the pdf file but could not open it, when i open the file it simply says that

"Adobe reader can't open this file because it is either not a supported file type or the file has been damaged (for eg: it was sent as an email attachment and was not correctly decoded)"

MY code is below:

```
<?php
$file = "testFile.pdf";
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$file");

readfile($file);
fclose ($fd);
?>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the PDF file format specification? a PDF file is not a plain text format, but the PHP you've posted simply writes out strings (presumably in ASCII encoding) to the response stream - that's not PDF at all.

Comment: Are two lines of text like that a valid PDF file?  After you write the file server-side, are you able to open it at all even without sending it over HTTP?

Comment: I don't know how to write handle pdf file in php or you can say i am newbie so i don't know the tricky things, can you please help me to open and then read the pdf file in browsers? A little bit code is appreciated.

Comment: @user2226181: Well, to create a valid PDF file you'd have to follow the specific format of that file type.  You can't just give it a `.pdf` extension and expect it to be a PDF file.  There are a lot of libraries out there to help with this.  You might start with something like this: http://www.pdflib.com

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that directory? Why don't you set an absolute path for your file so you can know where the file is actually created, and you'll be able to set permissions for that directory. Also, turn on your error reporting so you can get more of an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Some other options in regard to PDF libraries... Try looking into fPDF and TDPDF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating a PDF file.  You are creating a text file and putting .pdf as the extension which won't work.

An easy solution is to use [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).